# Cross Domain Policy with JSON feeds and Dashcode. Is there a way to use JSONP and implement it with the datasource feature in dashcode UI?

Tags: json, web-applications, cross-domain, datasource, dashcode

I'm just trying to get data from a json feed from an external server into my webapp.

I don't know enough about javascript to custom build my webapp so I was relying on the dashcode UI (specifically the datasources, dragging fields, etc.)

Is there a way to get around the cross domain policy and continue to use the datasource part of dashcode?  I tried doing a JSONP request, but whenever I put the .js file into the datasources it says it is not a valid feed.

Please tell me if it is possible to get around the crossdomain policy while also continuing to use the dashcode datasource UI to assign values such as title and content easily into the webapp.

This explanation might be a little confusing, I'm just concerned that it won't be possible to continue using the datasource UI because the code is not actually being run until the app is launched.  Just looking for some clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Click on “Widget Attributes” in the left-hand source pane. Under “Network / Disk Access”, make sure that “Allow Network Access” is checked.